# Minimum sum of products of elements from two arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I was practicing competitive programming for a while and a random question popped up in my mind. I couldn't find the solution to this on online websites thus posting it here.

Given two arrays `A` and `B` containing integers and having the same size `n`. I need to create a one-one and onto mapping from elements of `A` to elements of `B`. Let's say the paired elements are `{(p1A,p1B),(p2A,p2B),.....,(pnA,pnB)}`. I need to find the mapping which minimizes `p1A*p1B + p2A*p2B + .... + pnA*pnB`.

How can we approach this problem? It would be very helpful if you can provide the proof of correctness with your answer.

Comment: I assume (a) elements do not have to be paired in order, and (b) each element has to be paired exactly once? In other words, find a permutation/shuffling `A'` of `A` such that `sum(A'[i]*B[i] for all i)` is minimal?

Comment: Not tried, and certainly no proof, but my intuition would be to pair the largest from A with the smallest from B and so on.

Comment: Are elements always positive / non nrgative?

Comment: @tobias_k yes you need to find a permutation/shuffling A' of A such that sum(A'[i]*B[i] for all i) is minimal?

Comment: @amit it is not a standard question on any website so I was trying to find a solution with no constraints ie. the numbers are integers (both positive or negative). But I would like to know if an easy solution exists if the numbers are given to be positive.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like @tobias_k's solution from the comments would work.

Proof:
Without loss of generality, `A` is sorted (`A[i] <= A[i+1]`) and we can only permute `B`.
If there exists `i` such that `B[i] < B[i+1]` then by swapping those elements the sum changes by

```
new_sum - old_sum = A[i]*B[i+1] + A[i+1]*B[i] - A[i]*B[i] - A[i+1]*B[i+1] 
                  = A[i](B[i+1] - B[i]) - A[i+1](B[i+1] - B[i]) 
                  = (A[i] - A[i+1])(B[i+1] - B[i])
                  <= 0
```

Then for any starting permutation of `B` we can bubblesort `B` into being sorted in descending order while the sum does not increase. QED.

So, the algorithm is simply to sort `A` in ascending order and `B` in descending order to get the mapping.

Comment: Seems right to me. For making it easier to follow, you might add 2nd line `= A[i](B[i+1] - B[i]) + A[i+1](B[i] - B[i+1]` and second-to-last line `= [neg] * [pos]`